# Report back progress of long request on Google Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm working on implementing a web application, with Google Appengine as the backend, on which the expected behaviour is as follows:

1. User selects a couple of parameters for a complex analysis
2. User presses 'Start'
3. An initially empty 'response' page is returned to the user, but the processing continues
4. The analysis somehow continues on the server and as partial results are being computed they are shown / added in the response page.

I'm expecting the total computation to be around 30-40 seconds (so way under the 60 seconds required by Appengine).

Steps 1 and 2 are trivial. I know step 4 could somehow be completed using step AJAX, but I'm not sure how exactly I could implement step 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the task queue and the datastore. You need 3 handlers:

1. The task handler, doing the hard work. It will store its progress in the datastore.
2. A handler that starts the task in the background and returns the 'blank' page
3. A handler to get the status

Note: The page cannot be really blank. It must have javascript on it that checks the status. I think this is true with the `Channel API` too.

Anyway heres the code in Python:

```
class LongTaskStatus(ndb.Model):
  is_complete = ndb.BooleanProperty()
  percentage = ndb.FloatProperty()
  messages = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)

class LongTaskHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    # Query for existing status model or create a new one

    # Does work ...

    # Update progress
    status = LongTaskStatus()
    status.messages.appen('Still busy...')
    status.put()

    # Does work ...

class StartHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    # start the task
    taskqueue.add(url='/longtask')

    # Return a page which uses javascript to check the progress every few seconds
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('taskprogress.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

class CheckTaskStatus(wenapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    query = LongTaskStatus.query().fetch(1)
    result = {}
    if query:
      status = query[0]
      result = {
        'is_complete': status.is_complete,
        'percentage': status.percentage,
        'messages': status.messages
      }
    self.response.write(json.dumps(result))
```

and heres the "blank" page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <script>
      window.setInterval(function(){
        $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
          $( ".status" ).html( data );
        });
      }, 5000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit: Other option without Task Queue**

If you have a unique way of identifying the task **before it is started** you could potentially speed this method up by not using the task queue api.

Heres how:

1. Call the LongTaskHandler via javascript
2. Redirect to a loading page, which calls CheckTaskStatus.

This should be faster than using task queues, but unfortunately you need a way to identify the task before it is started. eg userid, session etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that such an approach would work. But I'm a bit afraid of the delay between the moment a task is added to the queue and when it is processed... Isn't this quite significant (tens of seconds at least)? Because, if that's the case, a considerable delay would appear for the users (considering that the processing should only take 30-40 seconds) and they would have to wait looking at a screen with a 'loading' indicator.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to return immediately is to start a background task.

Comment: I just thought of a way to avoid the task queue, I edited my post with it. Also, have a look here for some information about controlling task queues: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue

Comment: Hmmm... this looks interesting... But what exactly do you mean by 'identifying the task'? If, supposedly, the task would be to take two numbers `a` and `b` and compute something with them (so that no matter how many times the page is called with the same values, the same result is returned), could the `a` and `b` used to identify it (eventually together with a session id)? And what would I need to _identify_?

Comment: If 2 users call a task at the same time, you will need a way to query for the correct status. You can use the two numbers: `query_status.id = a + '+' + b` and then query for that status.

Comment: Thats difficult to answer though, because it depends on your application. Also think about how long you want to keep the results in the datastore etc.

Comment: I think it might be even better in combination with Channels API: 1. when the client loads the 'results' page, a Channel is loaded and sent to him; 2. the client calls the LongTaskHandler via javascript 3. the client listens to updates on the channel and status updates are sent from the LongTaskHandler

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/). It allows you to push messages from server to client.

Comment: I had seen it, but still I don't know exactly which would be the steps for my situation. I mean... if I send the response back to the client with the new channel id and the 'empty' response page, I'm not able to continue processing things on the server.